# Wordpress current version is 5.7.5 but I'm being prompted to "upgrade" to 4.9

Tags: updates, wordpress-version

[image]

I've tried reading various forums but can't find this issue anywhere.

My site is a managed WordPress site hosted on GoDaddy with access to the cPanel and file manager to modify files if necessary.

Comment: what happens if you disable all your plugins?

Comment: Actual WordPress version is 5.9. if it prompts you to update to another version and Your WP is managed by Godaddy, then contact their support....

Comment: What does it say in `wp-includes/version.php`? Maybe try a fresh installation of the core files.

Comment: @admcfajn it shows the correct version of `$wp_version = '5.7.5';`

Comment: @SébastienSerre GoDaddy does not support WordPress management, just hosting.

Comment: @rudtek that's the issue. I have the option to update to 5.9 if I disable all plugins. I need to figure out which plugin is causing this issue. Thanks for the help.

Comment: What about the following mysql? SELECT * FROM `wp_options` where option_name = 'db_version' does it show 5.7.5?

Comment: So it would seem that one of your plugins is the culprit...disable each until you find the one that is causing it.